# Postgres & Rust R2D2: How to get array_to_json as text/string without the escaped double quotes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust, postgresql-9.5, rust-cargo

I have the following SQL:

```
select jsonb_agg(t) 
from ( 
 select username, notifications 
 from useraccountview where username = 'Bobby'
) t;
```

This gives me following in PSQL:

```
[{"username":"Bobby","notifications":0}]
```

When I put a `::text`:

```
select jsonb_agg(t)::text 
from (
  select username, notifications 
  from useraccountview where username = 'Bobby'
) t;
```

I still get the same:

```
[{"username":"Bobby","notifications":0}]
```

However on my rust app's side using r2d2_postgres, I get an escaped string instead:

```
"[{\"username\":\"Bobby\",\"notifications\":0}]"
```

Rust code:

```
let qr = conn.query("select jsonb_agg(t)::text from (select username, notifications from useraccount where username = $1) t",&[&param]).unwrap();
let value: &str = qr[0].get(0);
println!("{:?}",value);
```

Outputs:

```
"[{\"username\":\"Bobby\",\"notifications\":0}]"
```

How I can I prevent the escaping of double quotes?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) ` can be simplified to `json_agg(row_to_json(t))` or even `json_agg(t)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `json_agg(t)` puts a `\n` in between each item. `json_agg(row_to_json(t))` does seem to be okay though I think. The original problem of escaped string still exists though for those curious.

Comment: `jsonb_agg(t)` won't add the new lines

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, good to know. I will use that going forward. Now just need to solve the escaped double quote problem.

Comment: The quotes are only escaped during printing. They are not escaped in memory. Use `println!("{}", value);` if you want to print the value without the quotes.

Comment: @Jmb that helps. However, I have a further question. `println!("{}", value);` does print without those escaped double quotes. But when I use Actix `HttpResponse::Ok().json(value)`, I get the escaped version. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @Jmb nvm, I figured it out. Using `HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("application/json").body(to_send)` where to_send is `let to_send = String::from(value);`. If you post your response as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are only escaped during printing. They are not escaped in memory. Use `println!("{}", value);` if you want to print the value without the quotes.